# Is NSFetchRequest with an NSPredicate containing a NSManagedObjectID safe to pass across thread boundaries?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, core-data

If I've created an `NSFetchRequest` on the main thread like so:

```
NSManagedObject *bar = ...;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Foo"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.bar == %@",
                            [bar objectID]]];
```

Is it safe to pass this `NSFetchRequest` with an `NSPredicate` that contains a `NSManagedObjectID` to a background thread like so?

```
NSManagedObject *bar = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Foo"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.bar == %@",
                            [bar objectID]]];

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = ...;
[[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext new];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSArray *foos = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                        error:NULL];
}] start];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some example code in the [CoreData release notes for iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) that pretty much does this, so it looks ok.

```
NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
__block NSUInteger rCount = 0;

[context performBlockAndWait:^() {
    NSError *error;
    rCount = [context countForFetchRequest:fr error:&error];
    if (rCount == NSNotFound) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
}];

NSLog(@"Retrieved %d items", (int)rCount);
```